# Find and return item in Angular deferred promise

Tags: angularjs, promise, iteration, deferred

So i have a bit of a confusion with angular promises.

I have a service, storing a list of users

```
.service('user', ['$q','$http', function ($q, $http) {
 var services = {};

 var _def_userLsit = $q.defer();

 $http.get('/api/acc/getlist').then(function (data) {
    _def_userLsit.resolve(data);
 })

 services.getUserListQ = function () {
    return _def_userLsit.promise;
 }
 return services;
}])
```

after injecting it, i can load my list like this in a controller:

```
            user.getUserListQ().then(function (promise) {
            $scope.userHelper.userList = promise.data;
        });
```

no problem here, got the json in the $scope, then the watchers do their jobs just fine.

Here is the Json format simplified for the question:

obj 1  { id=4,  userName="foohuman",  $$hashKey="object:14"}
   obj 2  { id=444,  userName="barhuman",  $$hashKey="object:22"}

But i also want a user's name by id, and i need to run that several times ( depend on the post count ).

So my question here is, how can i return a user's name like a function call, from that promised list.

like a normal function would do, like this:

```
$scope.getUserById = function(  id ){
  return "foo";
  //some magic needed here
}
```

If i just iterate trough the userHelper.userList, it could be empty if it runs too early, so i need to load that trough a promise, but loading it, iterating trough, then adding a string to the $scope is not the best options, since it can run multiple times, so it can overwrite each other, pretty unpredictably if i store it in a single variable.

So any idea how can i return a nice simple string by the id, and not a promise?

EDIT: Ok, so i can't really return a nice string, because it have to be some kind of callback, but i can process the data from the promise, so i ended up loading user data into a array like this:

```
 user.getUserListQ().then(function (promise) {

           var uArr = [];
           angular.forEach(promise.data, function ( value, key ) {
               uArr[value.id] = value.userName;
           })

           $scope.userHelper.uArr = uArr;

        });
```

and in the html I can boldly write `{{userHelper.uArr[taskData.tOwner]}}`.

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're making promises harder than they should be by using the [explicit construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Your first code snippet can be replaced with this:

```
.service('user', ['$q','$http', function ($q, $http) {
    var services = {};

    var pUserList = $http.get('/api/acc/getlist');

    services.getUserListQ = function () {
        return pUserList;
    };

    return services;
}]);
```

Regarding your question:

> So any idea how can i return a nice simple string by the id, and not a promise?

This is the wrong mindset to have. For getting a user by their ID, you need to think in terms of promises. You don't know exactly when the data is going to be ready, so this means that your `getUserId` method should return a promise. You can write it like this:

```
services.getUserById = function (id) {
    return pUserList.then(function (users) {
        return users.filter(function (user) { return user.id === id; })[0];
    });
};
```

in your controller, you can use it like this:

```
myService.getUserById(4).then(function (user) {
    $scope.myUser = user;
});
```